# Paypal Payflow API Error: Invalid tender when trying to process credit card sale

Tags: paypal

So I am trying to process a credit card transaction with the PayPal Payflow API using a transparent redirect. I am getting an error that it cannot process the credit card. When I look at the transaction history in the PayPal account manager the response message is Invalid tender. The manager also only shows the card EXP date. It looks like the credit card number is not making it to PayPal.

Here is the post string that is being sent in the header :

PARMLIST:INVNUM=794487634&AMT=78.04&CURRENCY=USD&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=0920&csc=123

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The paypal documentation for transparent redirect mentions only 3 parameters(Acct, expdate and csc) but another required parameter "TENDER" is missing in that, for credit card transaction your PARMLIST parameter should look like:

PARMLIST:INVNUM=794487634&AMT=78.04&CURRENCY=USD&ACCT=4111111111111111&EXPDATE=0920&csc=123&TENDER=C

//C is for credit card